# Making sense of the formula $\operatorname{Det} (I+M )= e^{\operatorname{Tr} \ln (I+M)}$, especially in the infinite dimensional cases

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics

$\DeclareMathOperator\Det{Det}\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}$In physics literature dealing with quantum field theory, the formula
\begin{equation}
\Det(I+M) = e^{\Tr \ln(I+M)}
\end{equation}
appears frequently. Moreover, in the so-called infinitesimal cases,
\begin{equation}
\ln(I+M) \simeq M
\end{equation}
is used in analogy with the Taylor series for the usual logarithm.

What is worse, $M$ can be not only unbounded but singular as well, containing $\delta(x-y)$ for example and yielding
\begin{equation}
\Tr\delta(x-y)=\delta(x-x).
\end{equation}

I searched everywhere in order to find relevant materials and make sense of the outrageous formulae, especially the "Mathematical Methods of Modern Physics" series by Reed & Simon. However, I cannot find reference to start with.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: For trace class $M$ the standard definition in use is that of the Fredholm determinant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant .  Beyond trace class, one should proceed with caution if one wants to be fully rigorous, although often the formal manipulations favored by physicists can still lead to accurate answers in such regimes.

Comment: Yes I have to be extremely careful. So, do I have to approximate the singular terms such as $\delta(x-y)$ and send to the limit in order to justify their formal calculations? Are there some systematic methodologies to recommend?

Comment: Yes, but one does not have as broadly applicable a theory as that of the Fredholm determinant once one leaves the trace class and each individual manipulation of a non-Fredholm determinant often has to be treated by its own arguments.  One common technique is to somehow approximate or discretise or analytically continue the operator to be trace class or even finite-dimensional, take determinants there, and pass to a limit (or perform continuation), possibly after performing one or more renormalisations to ensure convergence of the limit or existence of meromorphic continuation.

Comment: For instance zeta function methods are popular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant .  The story here is basically a noncommutative version of the story of divergent summation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series

Comment: TeX note:  Use $\operatorname{Det} M$ `\operatorname{Det} M`, which takes care of the spacing automatically, rather than doing it manually with $\text{Det }M$ `\text{Det }M`.  I have edited accordingly.  More importantly, I think it should be $\operatorname{Det}(I + M)$ (as in the body of your post), not $\operatorname{Det} M$, in your title.

Comment: @TerryTao Is the story you refer to ("a noncommutative version of the story of divergent summation") written out in detail somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: @AaronBergman I don't know of a systematic study, but this classic paper of Simon introduces at least one type of regularised determinant that goes beyond the Fredholm determinant: http://math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/74.pdf (see Section 6)

Comment: Adding to the comment from LSpice: \operatorname{} makes the horizontal spacing depend on the context, and \text{} does not. Try `a\operatoranem{kos}b` versus `a\operatorname{kos}(b)` and the horizontal spaces to the right of $\operatorname{kos}$ will be different in these two examples: $a\operatorname{kos}b$ versus $a\operatorname{kos}(b).$ I've noticed that some people don't notice things like this until they're pointed out, and some people erroneously think things like this have no effect on the reader except when the reader notices them.

Comment: For what it's worth (which may not be much), I've had a sense for some years that many of these 'outrageous formulae' in physics that relate to 'infinitesimal cases' only look outrageous because we're all used to analysis over the reals/complex numbers -- IMO these things likely admit perfectly reasonable (even canonical) interpretations when considering analysis over the surreals/surcomplex numbers (potentially also in nonstandard analysis).

Comment: This one also has flavors of "umbral calculus". One of the underlying ideas there is: if an equation holds generically then it holds always. The caveats here are the words "generically" and "always". Once carefully defined, this might become a theorem. However, such formulas are often used when neither "generically" and "always" are carefully defined, yet are still correct because some pair of definition happens to work...

Answer (score 3):

<sub>rather than continuing the long sequence of comments, I switch to the answer box</sub>

**Q:** *How to make sense of the outrageous formula* $\ln\operatorname{Det}M=\operatorname{Tr}\ln M$ ?

**A:** You might first consider a diagonalizable  $M$, and then since both determinant and trace do not change if you evaluate them in a basis where $M$ is diagonal, the identity follows immediately.

If $M$ is not diagonalizable, decompose it into Jordan blocks and use the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#The_logarithm_of_a_non-diagonalizable_matrix)
$$\ln{{1\;1}\choose{0\;1}}={{0\;1}\choose{0\;0}}.$$

Comment: I think the essence of the asker's worry is about the infinite-dimensional case, where the story is much less tidy.

Comment: Right. I am worrying about infinite dimensional cases with 'singular' terms like $\delta(x-y)$..